# how can i stop video from playing if not point view

Tags: jquery, html, html5-video, video.js

js to play videos in my site

but i wanna stop playing the video if not in view point

i make this code

```
$(document).on("scroll", function() {
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  $( "video" ).each(function() {
    var pos = index.position();
    if (scrollTop < pos.top + 100) {
                $(this)[0].play();
    }
    if (scrollTop > pos.top + 400) {
                $(this)[0].stop();
    }
    if (scrollTop < pos.top - 400) {
                $(this)[0].stop();
    }
  });
});
```

but it not work for me and not show any error

this is demo page "http://jsbin.com/yaqozihita/1/"

Comment: I update it and add demo page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this code to detect if an element is in view or not. Iterate each video element, if isInView() is true, start video, if not pause it if not paused already.

Caveats: you need to make sure the video has loaded at least metadata or the video element may cause errors. Use `preload="auto"` and the `canplay` event to detect this stage in advance (not shown here).

```js
function isInView(el) {
  var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();           // absolute position of video element
  return !(rect.top > $(window).height() || rect.bottom < 0);   // visible?
}

$(document).on("scroll", function() {
  $( "video" ).each(function() {
    if (isInView($(this)[0])) {                    // visible?
      if ($(this)[0].paused) $(this)[0].play();    // play if not playing
    }
    else {
      if (!$(this)[0].paused) $(this)[0].pause();  // pause if not paused
    }
  });  
});
```

```css
div {width:400px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
<h1>Scroll down to start video</h1>
Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... <br><br>

Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... <br><br>

Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... <br><br>

Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... <br><br>

  <video loop style="width:320px;height:auto;">
    <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.webm" type="video/webm">
            <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.ogv" type="video/ogg">
  </video>

<br><br>
Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... <br><br>

Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... <br><br>

Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... <br><br>

Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummtext ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... <br><br>

    <video loop style="width:320px;height:auto;">
    <source src="http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/devstories.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/devstories.webm" type="video/webm">
  </video>
Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummtext ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... <br><br>
Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummtext ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... Dummy text ... <br><br>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

for Pause use:

> $(this)[0].pause();

for Play use:

> $(this)[0].play();

tested on firefox and chrome

Comment: And what if there is more than one video on the page?

Comment: it work but if i go to top of the page it play all videos and if i play the video and go little down but i still in view point it stop it

Comment: add a check for the top of page(i think scrollTop returns 0 on top scroll position) and modify values for last two "If" checks..

Comment: doesn't matters if there are multiple videos $([selector]).each(..); iterates for each element matching the selection